# How to find the location of $\frac{(H-h)(3H-2h)}{5(H+h)}$ only by using a compass and a straight edge?

Tags: geometry

I have two points on a number line $x$ and $x+h=H$.

[image]

We are asked to mark the location of the third point

$$
\frac{(H-h)(3H-2h)}{5(H+h)}
$$

on the same number line but only by using a compass and a straight edge (a ruler without scales). How to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]By using a compass, we have to get the points $H+h$, $2H$, $3H$, $3H-h$ and $3H-2h$ on the horizontal line.

Next, by using a compass, we have to transport the points $x$ and $H+h$ on the sloped line and get the points $2(H+h)$, $3(H+h)$, $4(H+h)$ and $5(H+h)$.

Finally, we have to draw the line passing through the points $3H-2h$ and $5(H+h)$ and draw the parallel line passing through the point $x$ of the sloped line.
So we get the point $y$ on the horizontal line.

By applying Thales’ Theorem we get that

$\frac{y}{3H-2h}=\frac{x}{5(H+h)}$.

And, since $x=H-h$, it follows that

$y=\frac{(H-h)(3H-2h)}{5(H+h)}$

So $y$ is the required point.

Comment: Thank you very much! An excellent answer!

Answer (score 1):

You may use THALES theorem. You can calculate the segments H-h, 3H-2h,
.......

Comment: A nice hint. Reading Thales...